# How to see why a Smarty template fails silently?

Tags: php, smarty

I'm using Smarty templates which call object methods. I've put the code on a new server, but it silently doesn't work correctly. The template is being output, but is cut off at a certain point, probably because of an error.

`error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL`. Even with `$smarty->error_reporting = E_ALL` and `$smarty->debugging = TRUE`, no error is displayed.

How can I see why the template is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the PHP error log on your webserver usually stored in /var/log/apache/php.errors on a linux distro.

Comment: It's caused by a missing extension. Thanks!

Although the mystery still remains. `display_errors` is on, so all PHP errors should display in the browser. But that doesn't happen inside the template, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the php.ini option for 'display_startup_errors' is off, therefore it fails silently on attempting to load the missing extension without displaying/logging anything.

It does default to off since php 4.0.3, too.

Comment: It's not actually trying to load the extension, it's just calling one of its functions. Which doesn't exist when the extension isn't loaded.